# Generation of random string based on two characters in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to create a predefined number of rows, each having a predefined number of characters. The characters allowed are only 0's and 1's and are randomly generated.

I have achieved this with this code:

```
    Dim _allowedChars As String = "01"
    Dim randomNumber As New Random()
    Dim chars As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)
    Dim allowedCharCount As Integer = _allowedChars.Length
    For o As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
        For a As Integer = 0 To rowCharacters - 1
            chars.Add(_allowedChars.Chars(CInt(Fix((_allowedChars.Length) * randomNumber.NextDouble()))))
        Next a
        For a As Integer = 0 To chars.Count - 1
            'results for each row go here in a textbox line
        Next a
        chars = New List(Of Char)
        'row o finished, new line and go for next row
    Next o
```

This works great, an example output of setting 5 rows and 5 chars (only consisted of randomly generated 0's or 1's) is shown here:

```
11101
00000
11011
00000
01011
```

I now want to add an extra twist to it: specify the minimum percentage of 1's for each row, i.e. "even though randomly distributed, each row should have at least 20% of 1's". The percentage is based on the length of the chars in each row (variable rowCharacters in the code).

Anyone who could help me out on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim _allowedChars As String = "01"
Dim randomNumber As New Random()
Dim chars As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)
Dim allowedCharCount As Integer = _allowedChars.Length
'
For o As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
  Do
    For a As Integer = 0 To rowCharacters - 1
        chars.Add(_allowedChars.Chars(CInt(Fix((_allowedChars.Length) * randomNumber.NextDouble()))))
    Next a
    For a As Integer = 0 To chars.Count - 1
        'results for each row go here in a textbox line
    Next a
    chars = New List(Of Char)
    'row o finished, new line and go for next row
  Loop Until IsValidPercent(chars, 20)
Next o


Function IsValidPercent(chars As List(Of Char), ReqPercentage as integer) as boolean
'
Dim counter as integer = 0
Dim qtyones as integer = 0
  '
  IsValidPercent = False
  for counter = 0 to chars.count -1
    if chars(counter) = "1" Then qtyones = qtyones + 1
  next
  if qtyones >= ((chars.count/100)*ReqPercentage) Then IsValidPercent = True
  '
End Function
```